What is the residue of $f$ at $\infty$?
How do I compute the residue at $a = \infty$ of the function $\operatorname{f}$ ?:
$$
\operatorname{f}: \mathbb{C} \setminus \left\{{\rm i},-{\rm i}\right\} \to \mathbb{C},\quad z \mapsto \frac{1}{z^{4} + 2z^{2} + 1}
$$
Since $\operatorname{f}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus B\left[0,1\right]$ where
$$
B\left[0,1\right]\ \mbox{denotes the}\ closed\ ball\ \mbox{around}\ 0\ \mbox{with radius}\ 1,
$$
we will have ${\rm Res}_{\,\operatorname{f}}\left(\infty\right) = {\rm Res}_{\,\operatorname{g}}\left(0\right)$, where the function $\operatorname{g}$ is :
$$
\operatorname{g}: B(0,1)\setminus\left\{0\right\} \to \mathbb{C},\quad z \mapsto -\,\frac{1}{z^{2}}\,\operatorname{f}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)
$$

Now we could compute the residue of $\operatorname{g}$ at $0$.
I tried using the Residue Theorem for this matter, but can't seem to calculate the integral.

Maybe there's another way?

While you could compute the residue of $g$ at zero using an integral, there's hardly any reason to vs the usual  limit/series definition of a residue.

So I should try to compute the Laurent-series?

That'll suffice, yes.

I worked something out: $-\frac{1}{z^2}f(1/z) = - \frac{z^2}{z^4+2z^2+1} = - \frac{z^2}{(z^2+1)^2} = -z^2 \frac{1}{1-(-z^2)} = ...$. Using the geometric series we get $...= -z^2 (\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z^2)^k)^2 = (\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(z^2)^k)^2 = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(k+1)(z^2)^k$, so the residue is $0$. Does this look right to you?

Yes, that looks right. I encourage you to post that as an answer below to get further feedback.

To calculate the residue of $g$ at $0$, we expand $g$ into its Laurent-Series.
$$-\frac{1}{z^2}f(1/z) = - \frac{z^2}{z^4+2z^2+1} = - \frac{z^2}{(z^2+1)^2} = -
z^2 \frac{1}{(1-(-z^2))^2}$$
Now since $z \in B(0,1) \setminus \{0\}$, we can use the geometric series.
Then the latter is equal to $$-z^2 (\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z^2)^k)^2 = (\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(z^2)^k)^2 = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(k+1)(z^2)^k$$
where the last equality holds because of Cauchy's product formula.
Now we can see that the $(-1)$th coefficient of the corresponding Laurent-Series is equal to zero.
Hence $Res_f(\infty)=Res_g(0)=0$

Note that the function can be written as
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}
$$
so
$$
\frac{-1}{z^2}f(1/z)=\frac{-1}{z^2}\frac{1}{(z^{-2}+1)^2}=\frac{-1}{z^2}(1-\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^4}+\dotsb)^2
$$
for $|z|>1$. Since there is no way to get a term like $1/z$ from the expanison the residue is $0$.

A way I like to think about it (which is less painful perhaps): $f$ actually has a Laurent series at infinity too! Any function analytic on $\Bbb C\setminus B(0,r)$ for some $r<\infty$ will have this property. Moreover, since $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}f(z)=0$ one finds that $f$ is holomorphic at infinity, with value zero, hence: $$f(z)=-\mathrm{res}(\infty;f)z^{-1}+\sum_{n\ge2}a_nz^{-n}$$For all sufficiently large $z$ will hold. Here I use the fact that $[z^{-1}]$ coefficient is $-\mathrm{res}(\infty;f)$ (do a counter integral 'around infinity' and you'll see why); it therefore is very easy to find: $$\mathrm{res}(\infty;f)=-\lim_{z\to\infty}zf(z)=0$$Which is what you deduced in the comments by another method.
